# sublime3 on mac, how to modify plugin

Tags: sublimetext3

Seems the plugins are installed in `/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages`, I've installed a plugin called `JavaScript Completions.sublime-package`, and when I type in js, the 'function' snippet will be `'(function(){})()',` how can I modify it to be `'function(){}',` in the question I write it in one line, but the best snippet will be formatted and the cursor will be in the middle line.
So how to modify the snippet or can I write a snippet for myself in mac?

**One more question: how to write all snippets in one file ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own snipped:

1. Tools -> New Snipped
2. Snipped

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
        function(){${1:implementation}}
         ]]>
      </content>
    <tabTrigger>function</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

3. Save - named it `${Something}.sublime-snippet`

You can now start typing `function` in JS code and use `tab` to complete. The word `implementation` is automatically marked and if you start typing it replaces the word `implementation`.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how to add multi snippets in one file ?

Comment: First, if you think the answer was helpful, please up vote the answer too, so it gets more attention, if someone is facing the same problem. Second, imho it's no possible in snippeds, but you can create a `completion (.sublime-completions)` -> http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html